# How to show a custom notification to a specific user?

Tags: admin, users, notifications

I am new here, I found this spot interesting and very special. I've already found useful information through your discussions.

My first question is about user management. As Admin, I would need to display some text or notification on the dashboard of a specific user. For a "specific" user name, for example.

Comment: Hi, med, welcome! Yes, lots of knowledge packed in almost 26k Q&A's ;) Remember to show research efforts and what have you tried (if applies) whenever making a Question.

Answer (score 1):

You can show admin notices via the [`admin_notices`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) action. You can display it for a specific user by checking the contents of the global [`$current_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo):

```
function wpa80367_admin_notice() {
    global $current_user;
    if ( 'someusername' == $current_user->user_login ):
        echo '<div class="updated"><p>';
        echo 'This is an admin notice just for you, someusername.';
        echo '</p></div>';
    endif;
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpa80367_admin_notice' );
```

You could also extend this by saving per-user notices as user metadata via [`add_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta), then checking if a user has a notice in the above function via [`get_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta).

Another option is to display messages in a [Dashboard Widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) rather than admin notice.

Comment: Thanks Milo ...so I would have to edit functions.php by adding this custom code whenever I need to display a notice to a some user ... Is there a way to submit such notices from Admin Dashboard  by creating some form there ???

Comment: yes, this is just a static example. you could create a form to add user meta associated to a user (see [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)), then retrieve existing user meta in the above function.